# What DAO method I should use?

Tags: java, javafx, dao, ormlite

I have two comboboxes connected to a two DatabaseTables in ORMLite. For exammple first combobox shows brands (from brands_table) and second shows models (from models_table). Models_table has also foreignField with brandId. When I'm saving a new record, I must choose brand first then model.

For initializaton and set data in both of comboboxes I use *queryForAll* method from DAO.

My question is which method I could use for filtering data in second combobox when I already choose something from first. I was thinking about *queryForEq* and *queryForMatching*.

For now normal initialize is:

```
public void initializeModelsList() throws ApplicationException {
    CarModelDao carModelDao = new CarModelDao(DBManager.getConnectionSource());
    List<CarModel> listOfModels = carModelDao.queryForAll(CarModel.class);
    modelsList.clear();
    // loop
    listOfModels.forEach((c) -> {
        // create new object ModelsFX model
        ModelsFX modelsFX = ConverterModels.convertToModelFX(c);
        this.modelsList.add(modelsFX);
```

And what I'm thinking about is:

```
public void initializeFilteredModelsList() throws ApplicationException {
    CarBrandDao carBrandDao=new CarBrandDao(DBManager.getConnectionSource());
    CarBrand tempCarBrand = carBrandDao.findById(CarBrand.class, this.getModelsFxObjectProperty().getBrandsFXObjectProperty().getId());
    //it returns int with ID

    CarModelDao carModelDao = new CarModelDao(DBManager.getConnectionSource());
    List<CarModel> listOfFilteredModels = carModelDao.//searching for same ID in foreignField(brand_ID) in models_table
    listOfFilteredModels.forEach((c) -> {
        // create new object ModelsFX model
        ModelsFX modelsFX = ConverterModels.convertToModelFX(c);
        this.modelsList.add(modelsFX);
    });
```

Comment: I solved this already. In I use `List<CarModel> listOfFilteredModels = carModelDao.queryForEq(CarModel.class,"FOREIGN_BRAND_ID",tempCarBrand);`

Answer (score 0):

> My question is which method I could use for filtering data in second combobox when I already choose something from first.

If I understand, this is textbook example of foreign objects that is covered very well by the [documentation for ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/docs/foreign-object).  In the examples from the docs they have `Account` and `Order` which in your example would be `CarBrand` and `CarModel`.

To quote from the docs:

> You can query for foreign fields in a couple of different ways. The following examples show code which queries for all orders that match a certain account field. Since the id field is the name field, you can query by the name field of the account:

```
// query for all orders that match a certain account
List<Order> results = orderDao.queryBuilder().
    where().eq("account_id", account.getName()).query();
```

> Or you can just let ORMLite extract the id field from the account itself. This will perform an equivalent query to the above:

```
// ORMLite will extract and use the id field internally
List<Order> results = orderDao.queryBuilder().where().eq("account_id", account).query();
```